# Copy a single file to a non-existing folder

Tags: powershell

It's easy to copy multiple files to a folder that doesn't exists and let it be created:

```
Copy-Item C:\Temp\aa C:\Temp2\DoesNotExist
```

The command above will create the folder DoesNotExist. That's what I'm after.

But what is the PowerShell syntax to the same when the source is only *a single file*?

```
Copy-Item C:\Temp\test.txt  C:\Temp2\DoesNotExist
```

I tried C:\Temp2\DoesNotExist\ (with the trailing slash), but Powershell says "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." and refuses to copy the single file.

Comment: Well with a single file, you know the filename, so why not give it in the command? Copy-Item C:\Temp\test.txt  C:\Temp2\DoesNotExist\test.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for a one liner solution, you can do this.

```
copy "C:\test2.txt"  -Destination (New-Item "C:\Temp2\DoesNotExist\" -Type container -force) -Container -force
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Geoff Guynn's one-liner should be as follows:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\test2.txt" -Destination (New-Item "C:\Temp2\DoesNotExist\" -ItemType directory -Force) -Force
```

- The parameter for the cmdlet `New-Item` should be `-ItemType` and the intended "Type" should be `directory`.
- The additional parameter `-Container` for the cmdlet `Copy-Item` seems to me superfluous; on the one hand it is set to `$true` by default anyway, on the other hand a single file should be copied and not the folder structure should be preserved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.